# in struts where can we find the property_name of <bean:write name="name" property="property_name" />

Tags: struts, javabeans

I am new to struts and i am viewing an example of struts project and it has a table in which it has various number of data and to obtain that data from the data base it uses the code in the place of field to gain the data from database but i didn't see the name main_actvt_name which is the property anywhere.where can i find that in the action or in the form or in the jsp file.Guys help me out